# Bash: buffer entire stdin, then output

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

I need to modify a file **in-place** using a program `prog` that doesn't support it.

```
prog $file > $file.temp
cat $file.temp > $file
rm $file.temp
```

I want to do this in a single step, without temp files. This looks good but won't work:

```
cat <(prog $1) > $1
```

It **would** work if I had a way of buffering the contents of a pipe (blocking until the write end closes), eg:

```
cat <(prog $1 | buffer_until_close) > $1
```

How can I do this, or achieve the desired syntax some other way?

Comment: How about [Sponge](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge)

Comment: Sponge should be in [moreutils nowadays](https://github.com/madx/moreutils/blob/master/debian/control)

Comment: Why the aversion to temp files? There's really no such thing as editing a file in place; programs that seem to do so just hide the details of creating a temp file and replacing your original with it.

Comment: I'm not against temp files. I'm against my own code handling them explicitly :) it's a problem of expression, not of procedure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It would work if I had a way of buffering the contents of a pipe (blocking until the write end closes), eg:
>
> `cat <(prog $1 | buffer_until_close) > $1`

No, it wouldn't. The redirection of `stdout` (`>$1`) is performed *before* any program is started. And as soon as the shell sets up the redirection, it truncates the output file.

However, as mentioned in the comments, `sponge` will work:

```
prog $1 | sponge $1
```

`sponge` is found in the `moreutils` package and most linux distros will preinstall it.

Comment: Thanks! Not only what I'm looking for, but also a valuable lesson +1